# Removing objects from a list in python, Attribute error

Tags: python, list

I'm pretty much a complete beginner to python, and i'm having problems removing an integer from a list. I'm getting a error, AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'remove', and i don't know how to fix it. This is probably really easy to experienced eyes, and I have looked at past answers but keep returning same error

```
repeat = 0  
while repeat <= 4:  
    question_list = [1,2,3,4,5]  
    number = random.choice(question_list)  
    if number == 1:  
        print(question1())  
        repeat = repeat + 1  
        number.remove(1)  
    elif number == 2:  
        print(question2())
        repeat = repeat + 1
        number.remove(2)
    elif number == 3:
        print(question3())
        repeat = repeat + 1
        number.remove(3)
    elif number == 4:
        print(question4())
        repeat = repeat + 1
        number.remove(4)
    elif number == 5:
        print(question5())
        repeat = repeat + 1
        number.remove(5)
```

Comment: Well, can the reason possibly be `number` is an integer and integers don't have a `remove` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

`number = random.choice(question_list)` assigns `number` to an `int` returned from calling `random.choice` on your question list. If you want to remove from `question_list` call remove on the list not `number`:

```
 question_list.remove(x)
```

You need to assign `question_list` **outside** the while loop, if you put it inside you keep creating a new list so the remove never persists.

```
question_list = [1,2,3,4,5] # here
while repeat <= 4:
```

A nicer implementation may be to use a `dict` and just use `range`:

```
import random
# map numbers to functions
questions = {1:question1,2:question2,3:question3,4:question4,5: question5}

question_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # outside loop
for _ in range(4): # loop in range 4 
    number = random.choice(question_list)
    question_list[func]() # call function using dict key val
    question_list.remove(number)
```

Or simply store the functions in a list and randomly choose one:

```
question_list = [question1,question2,question3,question4,question5]
for _ in range(4):
    func = random.choice(question_list)
    func()
    question_list.remove(func)
```

Comment: I've changed it to question_list.remove(), however it doesn't seem to be removing the integers?

Comment: @zac, you need creating a new list, you need to create the list outside the while loop

Answer (score 1):

You should use the remove function on the list, and give the int as a parameter. So it should become:

```
question_list.remove(something)
```

But be careful, because if there is no "something" you will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Since a comment already explained why your code doesn't work, I'd like to suggest a simpler alternative.

It seems like you have a few functions you want to call in a random order.
There is no need to complicate things the way you're doing it, and mess around with removing elements from the list.

You can simply have a list of functions, shuffle it, and call every function in order:

```
questions = [question1, question2, question3, question4, question5]
random.shuffle(questions)

for question in questions:
    question()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but how do I get rid of the error when the functions have all be called?

Comment: >    question()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: There should be no such error. It sounds like you have a `None` in your list. You should show exactly what you have tried.